# alfresco how to configure gmail as smtp server

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

I want to use my gmail account to send email from alfresco explorer/share could you please help me from the beginning, how to configure the alfresco and gmail?
I'm using my desktop machine.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the following settings in your alfresco-global.properties file:

```
# Sample Gmail settings
mail.host=smtp.gmail.com
mail.port=465
mail.username=<user@gmail.com>
mail.password=<password>
mail.protocol=smtps
mail.smtps.starttls.enable=true
mail.smtps.auth=true
```

You've not mentioned what version of Alfresco you are using but here are further details:
https://docs.alfresco.com/4.1/concepts/email-outboundsmtp-props.html